# When RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport setMappingContext should be called?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I encounter issue when initializing my repository.

```
Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/config/RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.RepositoryResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must not be null!
```

It appears that the mappingContext is always null.

I have tried to debug it but I can't find anywhere in the code where setMappingContext is called.

Is there a way to initialize it myself ?

Comment: Can you share some code.
Most probably the error is with Autowiring. Also check your main class, if it has all the annotations, that are required

Comment: I wanted to keep my question general. How does autowiring failure can fail to set mapping context ? Here is a github link you can see the whole project and the code : https://github.com/kopax/spring-data-mybatis-demo-jclagache